# How to make SVG black bar with centered text responsive?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to make an SVG element fit to the bottom of the page with "Loading..." text centered regardless of the container's width. This is my current code which isn't working as the message is always in a fixed position.

```
<svg id="svg-bottom" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs></defs>
<g id="bottom">
    <rect height="40" width="100%" y="0" x="0" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.676460598" id="panel"></rect>
    <text id="status" font-family="GothamRounded-Medium, Gotham Rounded" font-size="20" font-weight="400" fill="#FFFFFF">
        <tspan x="190.97" y="16">Loading…</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above with the following:

```
<text font-family="GothamRounded-Medium, Gotham Rounded" font-size="20" font-weight="400" fill="#FFFFFF" x="50%" y="50%" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Loading…</text>
```